# Boto scanning a dynamodb table from item 1000 to 2000

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I have a dynamodb table. And I want to build a page where I can see the items in the table. But since this could have tens of thousand of items, I want to see them in 10 items per page. How do I do that? How to scan items 1000 to 2000?

```
import boto

db = boto.connect_dynamodb()

table = db.get_table('MyTable')
res = table.scan(attributes_to_get=['id'], max_results=10)

for i in res:
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 1000~2000 items?

There is no global order of hash keys (primary or index), thus it's hard to define the 10000~20000 items in advance.

However, it makes perfect sense if you'd like to find the ***next*** 1000 items, given the last return item. To fetch the next page, you execute the scan method again by providing the primary key value of the last item in the previous page so that the scan method can return the next set of items. The parameter name is `exclusive_start_key` and its initial value is None.

See more details in official docs.